# How do I use the round function and the absolute value function together in one line?

Tags: python, rounding, pong

I am attempting to make a pong program in python, and I want to make it so that the program shows the speed of the ball. However, despite getting this to work, the ball speed shown is too specific for what I want. It shows the ball speed to a very specific amount.

Here is my code in text:

`pen2.write("Ball Speed: {}".format(abs(ball.dx)), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))`

> "pen2" is my pen, and `ball.dx` is the speed of the ball on the x way (which is the same as the `y-speed`). I already have an absolute value function here to make it positive(because when the ball hits walls/paddles it multiplies speed by negative 1), but I can't figure out how to put in around function with the absolute value function to make it simplify the text.

Here is what my game looks like right now, with ball speed shown at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just do `round(abs(ball.dx)`. Here is your final code:

```
pen2.write("Ball Speed: {}".format(round(abs(ball.dx))), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I misread your question. The `round()` function takes a second argument specifying the number of decimal points, so just use something like:

```
pen2.write("Ball Speed: {}".format(round(abs(ball.dx), 3)), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
```

**Old answer:**
It seems like you just need to use a more specific format string, e.g. if you wanted to show it to 3 decimal places:

```
pen2.write("Ball Speed: {:.3f}".format(abs(ball.dx)), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
```

For more reference, you can check out the [tutorial here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). The gist of it is that the `:` tells the python interpreter that you're specifying the format, and `.3f` says you want to format a float with 3 decimal places.